# Algoritmo de Breadcrumb em ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou escrevendo um sistema em [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) e a ideia é que nas telas exista um Breadcrumb em todas as telas. Sem ideias para um bom algoritmo, bolei um Helper que devolve uma lista de objetos de acordo com a rota acessada. O arquivo está reproduzido abaixo:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MeuProjeto.ViewModels;

namespace MeuProjeto.Helpers
{
    public static class BreadcrumbHelper
    {
        private static readonly Dictionary<String, List<BreadcrumbViewModel>> Breadcrumbs = 
            new Dictionary<string, List<BreadcrumbViewModel>>
            {
                { "/Pessoas", 
                    new List<BreadcrumbViewModel> {
                        new BreadcrumbViewModel { Title = "Gestão de Colaboradores" },
                        new BreadcrumbViewModel { Title = "Lista de Pessoas" }
                    }
                },
                { "/Pessoas/Index", 
                    new List<BreadcrumbViewModel> {
                        new BreadcrumbViewModel { Title = "Gestão de Colaboradores" },
                        new BreadcrumbViewModel { Title = "Lista de Pessoas" }
                    }
                },
                { "/Pessoas/Create", 
                    new List<BreadcrumbViewModel> {
                        new BreadcrumbViewModel { Title = "Gestão de Colaboradores" },
                        new BreadcrumbViewModel { Title = "Dados Pessoais" }
                    }
                },
                { "/Pessoas/Edit", 
                    new List<BreadcrumbViewModel> {
                        new BreadcrumbViewModel { Title = "Gestão de Colaboradores" },
                        new BreadcrumbViewModel { Title = "Dados Pessoais" }
                    }
                }
            };

        public static IEnumerable<BreadcrumbViewModel> GetBreadcrumbs(String url)
        {
            return Breadcrumbs[url];
        }
    }
}
```

Pra eu obter a lista de Breadcrumbs de acordo com a rota que eu estou, é simples: coloquei no código do controller comum o seguinte:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Breadcrumb()
{
    return PartialView(BreadcrumbHelper.GetBreadcrumbs(Request.Path));
}
```

E na View `Shared/_Layout.cshtml` o seguinte:

```
<body>
    <!-- Page background -->
    <div id="page-background-gradient">
    </div>
    <div id="page-background-glare">
    </div>
    <!-- /Page background -->
    @Html.Partial("_SectionHeader")
    @Html.Partial("_MainNavigation")
    @Html.Action("Showcase")

    @Html.Action("Breadcrumb")

    <section id="content" class="row">
        @RenderBody()
    </section>
    @Html.Partial("_SectionFooter")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery.datatables")

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

O resultado na View fica assim para `http://localhost:12345/Pessoas`:

> Início > Gestão de Colaboradores > Lista de Pessoas

Isso funciona bem, mas vejo dois problemas:

- O esquema obviamente explode se eu criar um controller novo e não adicionar as novas rotas no `BreadcrumbHelper`;
- É facil de ver que a organização da solução é prolixa e redundante. Queria algo mais simples e mais performático, mas não consegui pensar em algo melhor.

Ideias?

Comment: Se tudo que está num mesmo controller tem o mesmo pai na hierarquia (como parece o caso de "Gestão de Colaboradores"), você poderia guardar essa parte como propriedade do controller, não? Ficaria mais coupled, porém menos repetitivo.

Comment: É uma ideia, mas eu queria deixar o máximo de coisas dentro do `BreadcrumbHelper`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tentei usar o `SiteMapProvider`, mas ele não é compatível com o MVC5, então tive que continuar aprimorando minha solução.

A solução segue a linha do sugerido pelo @iuristona, mas adaptado à realidade que eu tenho aqui.

### Helpers\BreadcrumbHelper.cs

```
namespace MeuProjeto.Helpers
{
    public static class BreadcrumbHelper
    {
        private static readonly BreadcrumbDictionary Breadcrumbs =
            new BreadcrumbDictionary
            {
                new BreadcrumbViewModel { 
                    RouteIdentifier = "Pessoas", 
                    Title = "Gestão de Colaboradores",
                    Children = new BreadcrumbDictionary
                    {
                        new BreadcrumbViewModel
                        {
                            RouteIdentifier = "Index",
                            Title = "Lista de Pessoas",
                            Children = null
                        },
                        new BreadcrumbViewModel
                        {
                            RouteIdentifier = "Create",
                            Title = "Dados Pessoais",
                            Children = null
                        },
                        new BreadcrumbViewModel
                        {
                            RouteIdentifier = "Edit",
                            Title = "Dados Pessoais",
                            Children = null
                        }
                    }
                },
                new BreadcrumbViewModel
                {
                    RouteIdentifier = "WelcomeKit",
                    Title = "Kit de Boas Vindas", 
                    Children = new BreadcrumbDictionary
                    {
                        new BreadcrumbViewModel
                        {
                            RouteIdentifier = "ServiceDesk",
                            Title = "Service Desk",
                            Children = null
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

        /// <summary>
        /// Retorna uma lista de Breadcrumbs de acordo com a rota passada como String.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="url">Rota</param>
        /// <returns>Lista de Breadcrumbs</returns>
        public static IEnumerable<BreadcrumbViewModel> GetBreadcrumbs(String url)
        {
            var splittedUrl = url.Split('/');
            if (Breadcrumbs.Contains(splittedUrl[1]))
            {
                yield return Breadcrumbs[splittedUrl[1]];
                foreach (var item in
                    GetChildrenBreadcrumb(Breadcrumbs[splittedUrl[1]].Children,
                        String.Join("/", splittedUrl.SubArray(1, splittedUrl.Length - 1))))
                {
                    yield return item;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                yield return new BreadcrumbViewModel();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Função recursiva que acumula o breadcrumb atual + os filhos.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="childrenList">Lista atual de Breadcrumbs (children da chamada anterior)</param>
        /// <param name="remainingRoute">Rota que falta ser retornada</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static IEnumerable<BreadcrumbViewModel> GetChildrenBreadcrumb(BreadcrumbDictionary childrenList,
            String remainingRoute)
        {
            var splittedUrl = remainingRoute.Split('/');
            if (splittedUrl.Count() == 1) yield break;
            if (splittedUrl[1] == "") yield break;

            if (splittedUrl.Count() > 2)
            {
                foreach (var item in GetChildrenBreadcrumb(childrenList[splittedUrl[1]].Children, String.Join("/", splittedUrl.SubArray(1, splittedUrl.Length - 1))))
                {
                    yield return item;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (childrenList != null && childrenList[splittedUrl[1]] != null)
                    yield return childrenList[splittedUrl[1]];
                else
                    yield return new BreadcrumbViewModel();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### ViewModels\BreadcrumbViewModel.cs

```
namespace MeuProjeto.ViewModels
{
    public class BreadcrumbViewModel
    {
        public String RouteIdentifier { get; set; }
        public String Title { get; set; }
        public BreadcrumbDictionary Children { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### Helpers\KeyedCollections\BreadcrumbDictionary.cs

```
namespace MeuProjeto.KeyedCollections
{
    public class BreadcrumbDictionary : KeyedCollection<String, BreadcrumbViewModel>
    {
        protected override string GetKeyForItem(BreadcrumbViewModel item)
        {
            return item.RouteIdentifier;
        }
    }
}
```

### Controllers\CommonController.cs

```
namespace MeuProjeto.Controllers
{
    public class CommonController : Controller
    {
        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult Breadcrumb()
        {
            return PartialView(BreadcrumbHelper.GetBreadcrumbs(Request.Path));
        }
    }
}
```

### Views\Shared\Breadcrumb.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<MeuProjeto.BreadcrumbViewModel>

<section id="breadcrumb" class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <a id="breadcrumbs-home" href="/" title="Página inicial"></a>
        <div id="pnlLinks" class="breadcrumbs home">
            @foreach (var breadcrumb in Model)
            {
                <span id="lblMenu2">@breadcrumb.Title</span>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 4):

Eu vou colar um caso em que criei para a montagem de um menu como esboço.

Declarei um tipo auxiliar:

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string Controller { get; set; }
    public string CssIcon { get; set; } // css do ícone
    public string Role { get; set; } // aqui defino a role que restringe a exibição do item no menu ou breadcrumbs
    public object RouteValues { get; set; } // parâmetros para rotas
    public bool HideOnBreadcrumb { get; set; } // em alguns casos não quero listar essa opção no Breadcrumb

    public List<MenuItem> Children { get; set; }

    public MenuItem Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Depois preencho o menu dessa forma:

```
    List<MenuItem> menu = new List<MenuItem>()  
        { 
            new MenuItem() 
            {
                Text = "Dashboard",
                CssIcon = "icon-screen-2",
                RouteValues = new { area = "" },
                Controller = "home",
                Action = "index"
            },
            new MenuItem()
            {
                Text = "Clientes",
                CssIcon = "icon-users",
                RouteValues = new { area = "clientes" },
                Controller = "clientes",
                Action = "index",
                Children = new List<MenuItem>()
                {
                    new MenuItem()
                    {
                        Text = "Clientes",
                        CssIcon = "icon-users",
                        RouteValues = new { area = "clientes" },
                        Controller = "clientes",
                        Action = "index",
                        HideOnBreadcum = true
                    },
                    new MenuItem()
                    {
                        Text = "Modelos de Contrato",
                        CssIcon = "icon-file",
                        RouteValues = new { area = "clientes" },
                        Controller = "contratoModelos",
                        Action = "index"
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        foreach (var item in menu)
        {
            SetParents(item); // método recursivo para ajustar os pais
        }
```

O método `SetParents`:

```
private static MenuItem SetParents(MenuItem menu)
{
    if (menu.Children != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in (menu.Childs))
        {
            item.Parent = menu;
            if (item.RouteValues == null) item.RouteValues = item.Parent.RouteValues;
            if (item.Controller == null) item.Controller = item.Parent.Controller;
            if (item.Action == null) item.Action = item.Parent.Action;
            SetParents(item);
        }
    }
    return menu;
}
```

Resolvi usar Areas pra ter bem definidos 3 níveis de menu. A partir disso em monto o menu completo, com breadcrumbs e submenus baseado no template html do meu projeto.

Essa pode não ser a melhor opção para o seu caso, mas deixo aqui como esboço de ideias.

Comment: Gostei da ideia parent-children. Acho que vou acabar seguindo essa linha.

Answer (score 2):

Pesquisando a algum tempo atrás a respeito da mesma dúvida, encontrei o seguinte link que me ajudou.

[Breadcrumbs on Asp.NET MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15116565/asp-net-mvc-4-breadcrumbs-with-dynamic-list-and-parameters)

Tenho certeza que pode ajudar você também, mesmo que não em 100% da maneira como ele fez, mas assim como no meu caso, mudando umas coisas aqui e outras ali, ajudou.

Qualquer coisa, só comunicar aqui que na medida do possível, vamos tentar ajudar

**EDIT**

[BreadCrumbs ASP.NET SiteMapProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066777/how-can-dynamic-breadcrumbs-be-achieved-with-asp-net-mvc)

Existe um outro link no próprio site do Asp.NET e no StackOverflow falando a respeito. Veja no link abaixo:

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada, mas a resposta ganha o accept só se tiver o exemplo em código.