# Problema com ViewBag e ViewData para Criação de Breadcrumbs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Estou precisando retornar do meu controller para minha view do projeto  dados para montar o breadcrumb (navegação estruturada).

Meu problema é: Se eu mandar por ViewBag ou ViewData ou TempData, e o usuário estiver usando duas janelas diferentes, posso mostrar os dados errados.

Existe uma forma mais "segura" de passar estes dados, além de ele estar presente no model.

Comment: Tenho mais um algoritmo que montei aqui e que é um pouco mais simples que este que marquei. Se quiser, reabro a pergunta e coloco ele.

Comment: Se conseguir deixar ambos os exemplos, seria interessante. Não tinha procurado como breadcrumb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A pergunta e respostas já existem aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7823/algoritmo-de-breadcrumb-em-asp-net-mvc), mas acho interessante colocar mais um exemplo de *breadcrumb*, considerando que deixei a abordagem mais simples nos últimos tempos.

As informações para montagem de um *breadcrumb* de até 3 níveis já existem no MVC, dentro de `ViewContext`. Um exemplo pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

```
<ul class="page-breadcrumb">
    <li>
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
        <a href="~/">Meu Sistema</a>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="~/@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]">@(Linguagem.ResourceManager.GetString(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()) ?? ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString())</a>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="~/@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]/@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"]/@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"] ?? "")">@(Linguagem.ResourceManager.GetString(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString()) ?? ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString())</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

`Linguagem` é um arquivo de *resource* (`.resx`) que contém todas as *strings* de nomes próprios de *Controllers*.

O CSS [é baseado no template Metronic](http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/templates/admin2/), cujo CSS coloco abaixo:

```
.page-bar .page-breadcrumb {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 6px;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.page-bar .page-breadcrumb > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.ie8 .page-bar .page-breadcrumb > li {
  margin-right: 1px;
}
.page-bar .page-breadcrumb > li > a,
.page-bar .page-breadcrumb > li > span {
  color: #888;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-shadow: none;
}
.page-bar .page-breadcrumb > li > i {
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-shadow: none;
}
.page-bar .page-breadcrumb > li > i[class^="icon-"],
.page-bar .page-breadcrumb > li > i[class*="icon-"] {
  color: #8c8c8c;
}
```